# Bootstrap 4 css file in Angular 5 CLI

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

> Context: I'm moving from AngularJS 1.x to Angular 5 and trying to
>   understand some points.

When I import bootstrap from npm modules in style.css or in styles array inside angular-cli.json the css content is merged into html after build.

Is possible to set the build to set a external css link tag instead? When I can set the build to copy bootstrap.min.css from node_modules to assets or vendor folter?

I could copy the bootstrap.min.css by hand into assets folder, but that's not in the CLI spirit. I also can't use CDN in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add link to bootstrap stylesheet in your index.html as normal

Comment: Yes, but how to move the css file from node_modules to assets folder using the CLI structure?